Invoking WebViewClient callbacks on WebView.reload()
I am creating an Android app using WebView. Here are the steps performed:

Show a progress bar at start
Load my webpage
If the page loads successfully, hide the progressbar and show the webview
If the page load fails for any reason, an AlertDialog will be shown with Exit and Retry buttons

Here is my custom WebViewClient implementation:
import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.view.View
import android.webkit.WebResourceError
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.ProgressBar

class MyWebViewClient(
    private val activity: Activity,
    private val logoView: ImageView,
    private val webView: WebView,
    private val progressBar: ProgressBar,
    private val headers: Map<String, String>,
    private val bounds: Array<Int>
) : WebViewClient() {
    private var success: Boolean = true

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
        webView.evaluateJavascript(
            "adjustPadding(${bounds[0]}, ${bounds[1]}, ${bounds[2]}, ${bounds[3]})",
            null
        )
        logoView.visibility = View.GONE
        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        webView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        Logger.log("onPageFinished()")
    }

    override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
        Logger.log("onPageStarted()")
        success = true
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
    }

    override fun onReceivedError(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?,
        error: WebResourceError?
    ) {
        if (!request?.isForMainFrame!!) return
        success = false
        Logger.log("Page load error: " + error?.description.toString())
        val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        builder.setMessage(R.string.unable_connect_server)
        builder.setNegativeButton(activity.getString(R.string.exit)) { dialogInterface, _ ->
            dialogInterface.dismiss()
            activity.finish()
        }
        builder.setPositiveButton(activity.getString(R.string.retry)) { dialogInterface, _ ->
            dialogInterface.dismiss()
            webView.reload()
        }
        builder.setCancelable(false)
        builder.create().show()
        webView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?
    ): Boolean {
        val url = request?.url.toString()
        Logger.log("shouldOverrideUrlLoading(): $url")
        if (url.startsWith(BuildConfig.SERVER_URL)) {
            view?.loadUrl(url, headers)
        } else {
            activity.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request?.url))
        }
        return true
    }
}

MainActivity.kt:
webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView.settings.setSupportZoom(false)
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
webView.settings.userAgentString = USER_AGENT
webView.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this), "App")

webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient(this, logoView, webView, progressBar, headers, bounds)
webView.webChromeClient = MyWebChromeClient(this)
webView.loadUrl(BuildConfig.SERVER_URL, headers)

Problem: If the webpage fails to load, the dialog is shown. But on clicking the Retry button in the dialog, the onPageStarted, onPageFinished and onReceivedError callbacks are not invoked.
Some posts around the internet said that those callbacks are not invoked if the URL doesn't change. Workarounds I have tried:

Modifying the URL by appending a timestamp and random string as arguments.
Using webView.loadUrl(webView.url) instead of webView.reload().
Clearing the cache before reload, using webView.clearCache(true).

But none of the methods worked. How to get those callbacks invoked for page reloads?
